# How to set custom two backgrounds with CSS?

Tags: css, background-image

How to set one background till half of the page and another background from half of the page till the end, while content div remains in exact middle of the page?
Please add an example!

---

```
<body><div id="right"><div id="content"></div></div></div>
```

css

```
body{ background:url("../a.gif") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;height:632px;} 

right{background:url("../r.jpg") repeat-x scroll right top transparent;margin-left:50%;width:100%;} 

content{width:980px;}
```

Problem - backgrounds is placed ok, but content div isn't in the middle of the page ....

ANY SOLUTIONS?

Comment: Can you paste your code from your own attempt?

Answer (score 1):

With css3:

```
html{ 

background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50) top left no-repeat,
url(http://placehold.it/50x50) top right no-repeat;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfkqd/

Center horizontally with

```
.content{
margin:0 auto;
width:200px;
height:200px;
```

}

(needs a `text-align:center;` to work in ie)

To center horizontally and vertically:

```
.content{
width:300px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
```

}

Comment: I need the same regarding CSS2

Comment: You're going to have to post an example than. With css2 you would end up needing another div and setting widths etc.

Comment: @Grillz no you don't; see my post.

Comment: nice. I assumed he would be using the body to do his centering.

Comment: @Grillz, he already said the content was in a div. that means the content div can be centered.

Answer (score 1):

without css3:

```
html
{
  background: url(...) x y repeat;//x and y for wherever it needs to start, repeat can be any value, up to you.
}

body
{
  background-image: url(...) top left repeat-x; // or no-repeat if you only want it once
}
```